# How did Gandalf get his staff back after being captured by Saruman in Orthanc?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, gandalf

In the books, it doesn't explicitly describe Gandalf's staff being taken or broken during his imprisonment in/on Orthanc, but in the film, Saruman is shown with Gandalf's staff, and Gandalf is shown to be without it during his escape. Later, during the fellowship's journey from Rivendell, Gandalf has his staff again.

Possible explainations:

- A mistake in the movie, and his staff should never have been shown to be taken from 
  him.
- He made a new one (I'm not sure how the Wizards get/make their staffs in the first place)
- He reclaimed it somehow (unlikely as this would have been described)

Comment: I think you would be well advised to take anything you see in the movie with a grain of salt, and instead read the books if you want the real story.

Comment: @TLP, you do mean the *original* story. Adapting it to film doesn't make the adaptation any less "real", only different.

Comment: @IlariKajaste I think you are confusing "*a* real story" with "*the* real story". *Top Gun* is *a* real story, but it is not "*the* real story" of *Lord of the Rings*. The movie version of *Lord of the Rings* is very different from Tolkien's version; hence, it is not "*the* real story".

Comment: @TLP I disagree. There is no "real" story of "Lord of the Rings". There's Tolkien's original version, and a few adaptations, including the movie. None of them are *the* real story. But since this seems to be a point of some discussion, it fits better to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3808892#3808892).

Comment: "Surely you wouldn't deprive an old man of his walking stick?"

Comment: In universe, the Lord of the Rings was a translation of the Red Book of Westmarch, written by Bilbo, Frodo, and Samwise, leaving the possibility that the Red Book is incorrect or has variations.  Canonically, there's nothing actually wrong with accounts differing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Talking specifically about the movie, I think Gandalf had a total of 3 staffs:

1. [The one that housed his pipe](http://www.flickr.com/photos/geekcentralstation/2348219490/);
2. [The one with a sort of crystal in it](http://www.council-of-elrond.com/castdb/gandalfgrey/gandalfgrey7.jpg);
3. [The White one](http://www.entertainmentearth.com/images/AUTOIMAGES/UC1386Wlg.jpg).

This is confirmed by [this FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120737/faq#.2.1.15) on IMDb.com. In the book there seem to be no direct reference to this fight (I checked the book and didn't find anything), so I think it is simply a difference in the movie.

Comment: Very cool! So does he make them?

Comment: @roviuser I don't know, honestly. I'll be looking into it, as I'd also like to confirm/deny whether this thing happened in the books too (which I honestly can't remember).

Comment: Ok I checked in the book, and also as dlanod confirms, there seems to be no direct/straight mention of this.

Comment: The book DOES make direct/straight mention of the status of Gandalf's two staves. It is described in detail right here http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12940/1591 Where the staves came from, and who made them. I didn't remember either ;o) until I read that other answer though!

Comment: @FeralOink I meant that there was no direct mention that the fight with Saruman (as it happens in the movie) happened in the books too. :P I mean, in the book it doesn't say that Saruman took its staff, used it against him, etc... :) I re-worded the answer to make that clear. :D

Comment: Okay, @Alenanno! I'm sorry, I didn't mean to sound so grumpy. I was grumpy with someone else, not you. Some residual grumple accidentally ended up here!

Comment: @FeralOink You didn't sound grumpy at all! You did well to point that out. I don't like having flaws in my answers. :D

Comment: I thought the staff Saruman stole was different from the one he carried into Moria - the tangled roots at the top of the first staff were more numerous and less open at the top than the ones on the Moria staff.  The FAQ linked in this answer says the same thing:  "He doesn't get his staff back. The staff he has after leaving Isengard is a different staff from the one he had at the beginning of the movie. The two staves are shown in the Fellowship of the Ring Appendices 1 Design Galleries section."

Comment: From [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130918184047AATeJbl) "Gandalf's first staff in The Fellowship of Ring came to him from Radagast the Brown who loses his staff in an unexplained plot line. The fate of Radagast is set to be revealed later on in The Hobbit Films triology..."

Comment: "Fans of the Lord of the Rings movies have mistakenly stated that the staff Gandalf inherits from Radagast is the stave he uses in Moria. If one looks closely at the crown of the staff, the shape of the shaft and the symbol plastered onto the staff it is clear to the viewer that the first staff Gandalf weilds in the Fellowship of the Ring is the Staff of Radagast the Brown. He is seen with Radagast's staff until he loses it after his duel with Saruman at Orthanc. He acquired a slightly different looking staff in Imladris that held a powerful crystal which he illuminated in the Mines of Moria"

Answer (score 48):

In the books, Gandalf has 2 staves.

The first one which he has all the way up to the encounter with the Balrog. This is broken at the Bridge of Khazad Dum when he breaks the bridge. That staff was presumably created in Valinor as part of his incarnation as a wizard.

The second one is created by Galadriel for him (along with his new white robes) after he returns from death and Gwaihir flies him to Lorien.

Staves are clearly very important receptacles/focuses of power. Saruman is significantly de-powered after Gandalf breaks his staff for example.

In the books, his staff wasn't taken from him. This may not have been in Saruman's power to do. When Gandalf later breaks Saruman's staff, it is clear it is not a trivial event to do it, but rather a ceremony or spell. Saruman can use the power of Orthanc to hold Gandalf, but not "defeat him" as such, unless he gets the One Ring.

Comment: Sure, so what's your answer? He must have reclaimed it, or it was never taken from him?

Comment: In the books, his staff wasn't taken from him. THis may not have been in Saruman's power to do. When Gandalf later breaks Saruman's staff, it is clear it is not a trivial event to do it, but rather a ceremony or spell. Saruman can use the power of Orthanc to hold Gandalf, but not "defeat him" as such, unless he gets the One Ring.

Comment: Ummm, @anthony-arnold the answer right above says: ***In the books, his staff wasn't taken from him.*** The first staff broke. The second staff was in Gandalf's possession until the very end, when he crossed back over the sea to the West. Gandalf's staff was never taken from him.

Comment: I always thought it a conceit on Saruman's part, that he didn't take Gandalf's staff when he captured him at Orthanc.

Comment: @FeralOink Yeah, thanks. I think it's been updated since my comment.

Comment: Is there a reference for the last paragraph, especially the last sentence? Seem like very opinionated, contentious claims that should be backed up by something.

Answer (score 25):

His staff isn't taken from him in the books, so any definitive answer is purely movie-based.  Whether that's a mistake or just unexplained would depend on your opinion of the movies.

While only a secondary source albeit a very well-researched and well-accredited one, Ted Nasmith's artwork shows Gandalf retaining his staff as he escapes Isengard on Gwaihir's back.

[image: Gandalf escaping with Gwaihir]

Answer (score 13):

In the books we have no detailed account how Saruman was able to imprison Gandalf (most likely as a head of the order and known mind manipulator Saruman used some of his power to prevent Gandalf from fighting back, so he had no reason to take the staff from him, later orcs or Dunledings in his service took him through the stairs to the Orthanc's roof, where he remained until Gwaihir's rescue). 
The proof that Gandalf had his staff with him all the time could be taken from very realistic dream of Frodo:

> In the dead night, Frodo lay in a dream without light. Then he saw the
>   young moon rising; under its thin light there loomed before him a
>   black wall of rock, pierced by a dark arch like a great gate. It
>   seemed to Frodo that he was lifted up, and passing over he saw that
>   the rock-wall was a circle of hills, and that within it was a plain,
>   and in the midst of the plain stood a pinnacle of stone, like a vast
>   tower but not made by hands. On its top stood the figure of a man. The
>   moon as it rose seemed to hang for a moment above his head and
>   glistened in his white hair as the wind stirred it. Up from the dark
>   plain below came the crying of fell voices, and the howling of many
>   wolves. Suddenly a shadow, like the shape of great wings, passed
>   across the moon. **The figure lifted his arms and a light flashed from
>   the staff that he wielded**. A mighty eagle swept down and bore him
>   away.

Of course dreams may seem not the most reliable source but in this case it's rather certain (dreams of Frodo are often prophetic, this one was retroactive, as the event it concerned happened earlier).

In the movies it may be that Gandalf just made a new one.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, Gandalf losing his staff (during his capture in Orthanc/Isengard by Saruman) is not mentioned in the book.

As for the movie:

[image: comparison of Gandalf's staff in the films before and after capture]

And again, in Orthanc, about to lose it:
[image]

After Orthanc, with replacement:
[image]

Gandalf seems to have a somewhat different staff after losing the one in Orthanc. Presumably he replaced it.

Comment: Exactly.  I don't understand why people think they are the same staff

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly,chronology in Peter Jackson's motion picture adaption Gandalf acquired a new staff in Rivendell,the house of Elrond, as his first staff(Radagast) was taken by Saruman,in a flashback when he is at Frodo's bedside long before uses the replacement staff that illuminates with a crystal he puts into the crown of it to guide the fellowship through Moria

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is asking *how* he acquired the staff. Saying that he "acquired a new staff" is not helpful.

Comment: @amflare I believe the question how did Gandalf get his staff **back** after being captured by Saruman. This answer takes the position that he did **not** get it back, but instead acquired a new one.

Comment: Radagast is the name of another wizard, not the name of any staff.

Answer (score -1):

It was mentioned in the book and movie that the staff was taken from him by Saruman.
Gandalf didn't get his staff back but he has another. A Staff is just a tool. The new staff was given provided to Gandalaf when he got back to Rivendel according to the book. Thus, we can see he has a staff again.

Comment: If you could [edit] in some relevant quotes from the books, it would improve your answer greatly

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This contradicts the existing top-rated answer, which claims that Saruman taking Gandalf's staff *didn't* happen in the book. As fez suggested, if you can provide evidence that it *did* happen, and that he procured a replacement while in Rivendell, that would be a great answer.